# Extracting date strings from the JavaScript Date object without timezones being applied

Tags: javascript, date

I want to do a straight conversion of a date string and cannot get the results I expect. I expect the below code to produce a date equal to the date portion of the original string, but it seems to apply a time during the instance creation.

```
var usageTime = new Date('2012-01-19T22:59:50-0800');
console.log(usageTime);  // Fri, 20 Jan 2012 06:59:50 GMT

dayOfUsage = usageTime.getFullYear()+'-'+(usageTime.getMonth()+1)+'-'+usageTime.getDate();
console.log(dayOfUsage);  // 2012-1-20
```

I expect a date of 2012-1-19. What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getUTC*()` functions (`getUTCDate()`, `getUTCHours()` and so on) to get your times with no timezone offset.

Comment: That produces the same result. dayOfUTCUsage = usageTime.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+(usageTime.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'+usageTime.getUTCDate();
dayOfUsage = usageTime.getFullYear()+'-'+(usageTime.getMonth()+1)+'-'+usageTime.getDate();
console.log(dayOfUTCUsage);  // 2012-1-20
console.log(dayOfUsage);     // 2012-1-20

Comment: Well, you defined the time with an offset of -8 hours, so the time is in fact on the 20th in UTC...

Comment: I'm missing your point. The result is the same whether or not the UTC versions of the functions are used.

Comment: When you defined the date, you specified a timezone of `-0800`. Therefore, 8 hours are added to the time to get you to UTC. 11PM + 8 hours = 7 AM the following day.

Comment: I get that part. What is puzzling is that none of the methods on Date provide access to the date as it existed in the timezone the timestamp was captured. I don't see anyway to extract the 19th.

Comment: I think the root cause is that the Date object is built for browsers and assumes local time matters the most. But in Node, you don't always want local time.